# wsdl issue in soap api call

Tags: apex, api, soap-api, wsdl, wsdl2apex

My first post,pretty excited.I want to make a soap api call which insert multiple records. I am using 2 different salesforce instances.
**destination side**

```
global with sharing class SoapDemo1
{
   global class AccountWrapper
   {
      webservice string Name;
      AccountWrapper(Account a)
      {
        this.Name=a.Name;
      }
   }

   webservice static List<Account> CreateMultipleAccounts(List<Account> accs)
   {
       List<Account> FinalList=new List<Account>();

       for(Account a:accs)
       {
          Account a1=new Account();
          a1.Name=a.Name;

          FinalList.add(a1);   
       }

       if (FinalList.size() > 0)
       {
          Database.Insert(FinalList);
       }

       return FinalList;
    }   
 }
```

I generated the class wsdl file and also partner wsdl file

****source side:****
I upload the class wsdl file generated from destination, when I parse no errors, but when I click Generated Apex code, it shows error as:

> Unable to find complexType for
>   {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/SoapDemo1}anyType

I changed anyType to string and again repeated the process but it shows error as:

> Unable to find complexType for
>   {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/SoapDemo1}JunctionIdListNames

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution for the given code would be to simplify the the parameters for the webservice method and the return type.

If you switched to taking a List of strings that represent the Account names and returning a List of strings that are the Id's of the new Accounts then the WSDL would be greatly simplified.

Or if you needed something a bit more advanced create an inner wrapper class for usage as either the input parameters or return type. It looks like you are already part way there with your `AccountWrapper` class. You just need to actually use it in the method for the parameters, and potentially the return type as well.

---

The problem  you are encountering occurs when you include an sObject in the parameters. You end up generating complex types in the WSDL that have `type="xsd:anyType"`. This doesn't have native support in wsdl2apex because the underlying `WebserviceCallout.invoke()` method doesn't know how to handle an arbitrary type.

If you really want to proceed with the web method unchanged you could try the version of Wsdl2Apex in the [FuseIT SFDC Exploer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) (Disclosure: The is my current employer). The version we made there will automatically convert the anytype into a string. You probably won't be able to call anything that depends on it, but you likely won't need to either.

Comment: Hi daniel, ur first solution worked perfectly.    webservice static List<String> CreateAccount(List<String> accName), I got the results. Thanks.   I went to FuseIT, downloaded the files but unable to install them because of app permisisons.

Comment: @DivyaManohar There should be either an installer or a standalone exe that might be easier to use. Glad you got it working.